# Node.js http response end event?

Tags: apache, node.js, apache2

I was using this piece of code to send some http requests and get data, and it was working fine. I recently updated apache and php to latest versions, as well as node.

And 'close' event stopped firing. I also tried 'end' and 'finish' none of this seems to be working.

I need to know when response is ended so I can start processing data, usually it comes in several chunks. Can you guys help?

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        if(chunk != null && chunk != "") {
            dataString += chunk; c
        } 
      });
    });

    req.on('close', function () {
        //tadaa it is finished, so we can process dataString
    });

    req.write(post_data);
    req.end();
```

Current versions: Apache 2.4, PHP 5.4 node 0.10.9

Maybe there is some particular config settings of Apache that prevents it from closing connection?

P.S. I do not think it is Apache though.. I tried google.com with same result.. pretty strange... Anyone have a working code example? (load big data, and know when it ended)

Comment: This might be an issue with [streams2](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/12/20/streams2/). Try adding `req.on('data'...)` or call `req.resume()` after `req.on('end')`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be waiting for the `end` event of the response, not the request.

e.g.

```
res.on('end', function () {
    // now I can process the data
});
```

Comment: This worked thank you! I am curious how this possible was working before... but anyway thanks a lot!

Comment: It's possible the newer Apache has something like connection keepalives turned on or similar, so it's not closing the connection after a single request.